# Move the text in a horizontally scrollable edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a horizontally scrollable edit text view in one of my dialog boxes (on the Android).  I'm trying to figure out a way to move/scroll the text all the way to the left so the right end of the whole string is visible.  I know I can do this by setting the selection to be at the end of the string, however, I need the selection to be somewhere else.  I've tried setting the selection twice, once to scroll the text all the way to the left and then a second time to be where I need it to be (4 characters from the end), however, it seems that the second selection set overrides the first and the first never actually happens.  The only way that I've been able to make it work so far is by delaying the second selection set by 100ms.  Here's what I've done so far:

```
mFilename.setText(filename);

mFilename.setSelection(filename.length());

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    int cursor = mFilename.getText().toString().lastIndexOf(".");
    if (cursor != -1)
      mFilename.setSelection(cursor);
  }
}, 100);
```

However, I'm thinking that there's got to be a better way of doing this.

Thanks,
Harry